# Why is IIS 6 / Windows 2003, forcing a Website to use .NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-6, windows-server-2003, asp.net-2.0

I have a Windows 2003 Server 64bit running IIS 6.0.

When I set the server up, I noticed that the 'ASP.NET' tab has been removed from the 'Web Sites' property in IIS Manager.

Now every website runs on .NET 2.0 and I need to change them to run on .NET 4.0.
I have ASP.NET 4 (32bit) enabled in the 'Web Service Extension' (the only other options ASP.NET versions 2 in both 32 and 64 bit modes).

I can confirm that in C:\Windows\Microsoft.net folder, there is both 'WOW' and 32bit .Net installation.

This is a production server with many websites and I'm afraid to run some IISReg scripts to put back the 'ASP.NET' tab.

When I try to the .Net 4 targeted website, I get an error:

> Unrecognized configuration section system.web.extensions

The version information shows .Net 2.0

So what can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: holy run-on sentence batman. I'm sorry but your question causes people to want to *not* read/answer.

Comment: You should have done the changes in testing or staging environment first. But since it's broke already, try to recycle the application pool of the broken website. This will rule out any cache issues. If it still doesn't work, you'll have to set it back to run ASP.NET 2.0 and recycle the application pool.

Comment: Sorry for the sentence! Was rushing through, I guess. The current setup was done because there were problems setting up ASP.NET properly in a 64bit environment. So I had to run some kind of 'regiis' like scripts which made the .net 2 target sites work. The assumption was that, even though there is not 'asp.net' tab, all future installed version of .net will work. Not happening. BTW, the broken website is not public yet--and hence room for tinkering web.config. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like why I setup the way I did many moons ago! http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/windows-server-2003-64bit-iis-6-32bit-asp-net-4-framework-and-targeting/

Comment: I think I have fixed the problem by making the new .NET site to run against .NET 4 by using instruction from my link above and from this: http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/tag/iis6-asp-net/ . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I indicated in my 'Comments' above, I had to run IIS in 32bit mode in a 64 bit system to target a certain web application. The background information for that can be see here:

http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/windows-server-2003-64bit-iis-6-32bit-asp-net-4-framework-and-targeting/

That resulted in running all websites in 32 bit mode with .NET 2.0. To get the new web application to run in .NET 4, I followed instructions, per:

http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/tag/iis6-asp-net/

Problem solved!
FYI.
Thanks.